# how to disable userinteraction for UIView when data is loading loading from webservice in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Hi How to disable **userinteraction** for `UiView` when data is loading from webservice.

I used the following line to disable user interaction,but it is not working.

```
self.view.userinteractionenabled=NO;
```

and I replaced **YES** when webservice ending.

It is not working and this creates `UINavigation` problem. Several more views are appearing when `didSelectRow` tapped.

Comment: what problem with your navigation...

Comment: Iam calling webservice in ViewWillAppear. if i go front view and return back and tapping DidSelcectRow continuously when websevice is calling(not completed), then it loads same view so many times and chaning back button to default navigation back button instead of my custom button.

Comment: this is because you are disable your view, and back button is in navigation and navigation is on window, so just disable userInteraction of window..check my answer.. thanks

Comment: If you like you can show some indicatore view like loading or uiActivityIndicatorView or can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/AalokParikh/MBProgressHUD) view to disable the interaction

Comment: if you need any code for it ask for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting userInteraction of view , so  its disable your view, but navigationBack button is on window , so disable window's userInteraction instead of disabling your view.

**here is code**

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appdelegate.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view.userinteractionenabled = NO;
```

This means user is not able to touch on `self.view` but if the page has `tabbarController` or `navigationController` user can touch on both.

So instead of this just add a new `UIView` on `window` and remove it from superview when your web services has finished.

Adding method:-

```
view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[view setAlpha:0.5];
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appdelegate.window addSubview:view];
```

and just write

```
[view removeFromSuperview];
```

after finished your web services.
And of course you will have to import `Appdelegate.h` for using the `Appdelegate`.